# Virtualmin/Apache and redirects

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, virtualmin

I am running Virtualmin and added a website to the system.
However, I have a problem getting it to run probably.

If I go to website.com then it redirects me to default website.com. However, if I go to www.website.com I am going to the website correctly.

This is my .conf file for the website, but I would expect there must be a configuration elsewhere in Apache that causes this redirect. I have no problems on any other of the virtual servers.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SuexecUserGroup #1020 #1018
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
ServerAlias webmail.website.com
ServerAlias admin.website.com
DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/website.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/website.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/website/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/website/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php7.0 .php7.0
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</Directory>
<Directory /home/website/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://website.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://website.com:10000/ [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your text refers to `website.com` but your config to `website.ie`. Please [edit] the question and clarify. They can't both be right ...

Comment: I corrected that, I made a mistake in replacing the name, a habit when posting. The website is actually http://brew132.ie.

Comment: There must be a setting somewhere that all request to an unknown  domain are redirected to the default website (as it is a redirect, not just showing the default website)

Comment: Perhaps check out Server Configuration -> Website Redirects?

Comment: It seems like it might have been a caching issue of some sort as the problem has resolved itself.